# Image in picturebox by image path url

Tags: c#, image, combobox

How do i get the image to be shown in winform after the url is typed / keyed into the textbox ? Below method applies for browsing image and then it'll appear in the combo box , Is there any other methods? as i've search for multiple it just doesn't work

```
      OpenFileDialog OpenFd = new OpenFileDialog();
       OpenFd.Filter = "Images only. |*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.png; *.gif;";

       DialogResult dr = OpenFd.ShowDialog();
        pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile(OpenFd.FileName);
       textBox1.Text = OpenFd.FileName;
```

Comment: Typing into the textbox is difficult because you either need to use a specific path and/or make sure that the long filename/path is spelled perfectly. This type of thing is much better suited to some sort of list, where you show the names and let the user select. Since you are using Windows Forms anyway, why make the user do all that typing? Is this a requirement or something?

Comment: Yes , As i'm doing like a function where you select the persons name and the infomation will come directly from database , thats the part where i need it to be this way

Comment: Ok- now I'm a little confused. The user selects their name from a database and what happens now?

Comment: It's just showing database colums in winform , and url will be at the textbox  , It's done , thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void yourTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(yourTextBox.Text))
            pictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(yourTextBox.Text);
    }
```

use TextChanged event of your TextBox

Comment: It worked just as fine , Thanks for pointing this out , couldnt find those method any else where .